# Проблема с прорисовкой полигонов на карте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть проблема с отображением полигонов на яндекс карте. На карте имеется ряд меток и полигонов. При первой загрузке страницы, проблем с их отображением нет, проблемы появляются если перемещаться по карте от одного полигона к другому, иногда он просто не прорисовывается, пример:

https://yadi.sk/i/xuNrn2kxvuDyLQ (некорректное отображение)
https://yadi.sk/i/YS0AopqkseUsWA (корректное отображение)

Так же если изменить зум карты над некорректным полигоном, недостающие части полигона появятся. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Больше похоже на ошибку железа, чем софта.
Попробуйте в другом браузере, или даже ПК, для начала.

Comment: Попробовал, ситуация та же. На мобильных устройствах так же прослеживается.

Comment: Похоже что-то с api не так
https://yadi.sk/i/ppEDuFu16uSVUw
https://yadi.sk/i/ITWJ04o0psCHIA

Comment: Хм. Я с API-карт знаком на уровне "поставить точку". Не помогу. Попробуйте задать вопрос им в техподдержку. Там ответят быстрее.

Comment: Меня сюда тех. поддержка и послала со словами:

"С вашим вопросом лучше обратиться на Stack Overflow: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yandex-maps-api . Там вы сможете получить ответ от других пользователей или наших специалистов."

Comment: Добавьте код, который формирует эти полигоны в ваш вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: Вообщем ладно. Буду ждать новое обновление api. Все таки грешу на это. А как возможное временное решение вариант с исп. гугл карт без исп. яндекс карт)))

Comment: Пример кода с проблемой: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/polygon

Comment: Хм. У меня все нормально. Увеличиваю - или уменьшаю - все нормально отрисовывается. 
Единственное, что в момент движения самого ползунка не происходит отрисовки, но это нормальная ситуация.  Почему? Потому что нету асинхронности. Что бы заново отрисовать карту под новый зум - API сначала должен получить данные о кратности увеличения\уменьшения.  Либо надо подумать - как бы передавать этот параметр постоянно - что глупость на мой взгляд.

Comment: на мой взгляд, некрасиво, когда при перемещении по карте от одной области к другой полигон прорисовывается не полностью.

Comment: Ага. Теперь я понял, когда это возникает. Больше похоже, что удаляется "лишняя" зона, может быть что бы ресурсы поэкономить. Незнаю...Но это не ошибка в коде